# How to find the unitary matrices in this exponential matrix representation

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, unitary-representations

In the following post
[Representing a product of matrix exponentials as the exponential of a sum](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82620/representing-a-product-of-matrix-exponentials-as-the-exponential-of-a-sum)
there is a statement regarding the result of the multiplication of two matrix exponentials:

if $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices, then there exist unitary matrices $U$ and $V$, such that

$$ e^{iA}e^{iB} = e^{i (UAU^*+VBV^*)}.$$

My question is, how do I calculate/determine the $Us/Vs$ in the above representation?

For concreteness can someone show this using $2\times2$ or $3\times 3$ matrices? or any $N\times N$ matrices?

Comment: In general, the U and V here will not be unique (this can be seen by a simple dimension counting argument).  The known proofs of the above statement are quite indirect and non-constructive; they prove that U and V exist, but do not give  an explicit recipe for finding such a U and V.

Comment: @Terry: interesting (I had mistakenly presumed that this should be "essentially doable") --- this makes the question more interesting now!

Comment: A partial computational result may be found in Section 4.2 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.2656 --- perhaps that result can be extended to the general case.